# Local push notification NEAppPushProvider never called

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

[image]I Configured my app to use local push notification, I’m still tried
I request for entitlement, I get the approval from apple, I created certificate for both application simplePush and SimplePushProvider With extension network included both certificate are included on a group id

```
let pushManager = NEAppPushManager()
pushManager.matchSSIDs = ["Tenda_6B8340","ouamassi", "Tenda_6B8340_5G", "192.168.1.7"]
  pushManager.localizedDescription = "PushProvider"
  pushManager.providerBundleIdentifier = "" // Here I put my id application of the 
 SimplePushProvider I created
 pushManager.delegate = self
 pushManager.isEnabled = true
 pushManager.providerConfiguration = [
  "host": "192.168.1.7”.    // This is the address ip of my Mac where the server is launched  
  ]
    pushManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { error in
     print("error? \(error)")
   print("is active: \(pushManager.isActive)")
  })
```

My SimplePushProvider is declared like this :

```
  class SimplePushProvider: NEAppPushProvider {
 private let channel = BaseChannel(port: Port.notification, heartbeatTimeout: 
.seconds(30), logger: Logger(prependString: "Notification Channel", subsystem: 
  .networking))
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  private let logger = Logger(prependString: "SimplePushProvider", subsystem: .general)
```

….

```
  public override init() {
    super.init()
    public override func start() {
      logger.log("Started")

   ….
```

The problem is that the SimplePushProvider is never called and pushManager is always no active, I m sure my real device is connected to the ssid included on pushManager.matchSSIDs I tried several ssid but still the same problem

I'm getting no error when saving NEAppPushManager

I really stuck with this problem several days any helps will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to implement Local Push and had the same problems as you.

I was able to get past the problems by following:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/705382

Got some logs that got me to understand the problem by using "Console.app" (just run "Console" on your Mac).